# Not picking up properties from spring security config

Tags: spring, file, security, properties

I am using spring security and have an auth-ref-handler. Inside of it I need to get a property yet that property is not getting set. If I do the same code in my spring MVC controller REST handler method, it works?

spring-security.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/TcatServer6/myapp/properties/myapp/myapp.properties" />

<beans:bean id="adsh" class="com.mycompany.security.ADAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/agent/**" access="ROLE_AGENT" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/supervisor/**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/r/views/login.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/r/views/loginfailed.html"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="adsh"
        />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>
```

In ADAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
@Autowired
@Value("${acr_url}")
private String acrURL;
```

I have the EXACT same code in one of my spring MVC controllers and it works! In my AuthenticationSuccessHandler it always gets null?
Spring is turning out to be a configuration nightmare with all these things working inconsistently.

Update: Based on the feedback and my test, I think this may be a bug in Spring. Try it for yourself. Just try to get a property out of a property file using the @Autowire or @Value annotations within a Spring AuthenticationSuccessHandler in your spring-security.xml...can someone else try it and see if they get similar results?

Comment: What happens if you move context:property-placeholder to your regular spring configuration xml file?

Comment: Why you have @Autowired on acrURL?

Comment: Evgeni has a valid question.  IF you are using '@Value', you don't need to use '@Autowired' as they are independent of each other.  Also, what does your myapp.properties look like?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have tried both: Autowired and Value separately and together. This configuration (all combinations) works in my spring MVC Controller but not in my authenticationSuccessHandler. I have tried with @Value by itself also and it doesn't work. This was originally in my app-servlet.xml and it was picked up in my spring MVC Controller just fine. This authenticationSuccessHandler just seems to be buggy. It also couldn't find the bean "adsh" if I put it in the app-servlet.xml file. I HAD to put it in my spring-security.xml file.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file, please? Also, do you have a description of which config file goes into which directory?

Comment: This works when I put it in my Spring MVC Controller but not my AuthenticationSuccessHandler. It's just one property file with one property in it, the acr_url.

Comment: Is this a bug in spring?

Comment: Did it work for you? I have the same issue.